# Azure DevOps on premise and installing Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Given:
Version Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2

I need help installing Azure CLI so I can use in the pipelines. Can I use the latest or do I need it to match my current Azure DevOps on premise?

Answer (score 1):

If you want use Azure CLI to operate with external resources, you may use the latest version. If you plan to interact with your Azure DevOps Server, Azure CLI does not support that: [Get started with Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops)

> The Azure DevOps Command Line Interface (CLI) is only available for
> use with Azure DevOps Services. The Azure DevOps extension for the
> Azure CLI does not support any version of Azure DevOps Server.

Comment: What is Azure DevOps Services? Any alternatives, I'd like to be able to list and set library variables using scripting in the pipelines? Like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#update-variables-in-a-variable-group)

Comment: @Rod Azure DevOps Services is like a cloud DevOps Server - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/devops. For Azure Devops Server, available rest API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0